# How does the Shaman Totem interact with Maple Wolves and Blood Thirsters?

Tags: werewolv.es

Can the Maple Wolf be lured by a shaman totem, the HTP doesn't make it clear.

Also, how does the lure totem work when the wolfpack have two kills due to a Blood Thirster? Do both kills get lured or does only one? If the latter situation, is it deterministic which kill will be lured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shaman's Lure Totem only affects the first target picked by the Wolfpack, subsequent kills are not redirected.

The Maple Wolf is not a member of the Wolfpack and is not redirected by the Shaman's Lure-Totem.

However, answering this question has made me wonder if this behaviour makes the most sense or not, and I may revisit the interactions in the future.